# Put LinkButton on GridView's cell and run javascript function when user click on it

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I add a GridView on page in UpdatePanel and put a Panel in one of cells and add LinkButton from code behind to this panel like below

```
Panel pnl = (Panel)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("pnlSteps");//pnlSteps is Panel's Id
LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
//...
pnl.Controls.Add(lnk);
```

when user click on each LinkButton I want to run a javascript's function,how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
Panel pnl = (Panel)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("pnlSteps");
LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
lnk.attributes.Add("onclick", "YourFunction();");
pnl.Controls.Add(lnk);
```

And in java-script create a function as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function YourFunction()
  {
        alert("function called");
        return false;//don't forgot this
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forgot to mark the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Raise OnClick Event on the function like this.

```
lnk.attributes.Add("onclick", "function()");
```